# jqm change select menu to basic list?

Tags: php, list, jquery-mobile

This might be really simple but I'm not used to this way of coding - How can I change this select menu:

```
$control .= '<select name="'. $this->_hash_value($hash, $xml_obj->value) .'" id="'. $this->_hash_value($hash, $xml_obj->value) .'" data-native-menu="false">';
foreach ($nameArr as $folder => $imageArr) {
            foreach ($imageArr as $image) {
                if (substr($folder, 1, strlen($folder)).$image == $xml_obj->value) {
                    $control .= '<option value="'. substr($folder, 1, strlen($folder)).$image .'" selected="selected">'. $image .'</option>';
                } else {
                    $control .= '<option value="'. substr($folder, 1, strlen($folder)).$image .'">'. $image .'</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        $control .= '</select>';
```

into a single list item (with the value of the currently chosen item) that leads to a basic list with all the items the user can choose from?

Comment: I think we need to see a little more code. Is there a `foreach` going on to iterate through the *$xml_obj->value* variable or does that stay the same?

Comment: I've just taken over this project and I'm honestly not familiar with everything yet. It's in an else if loop : elseif ($xml_obj->attributes()->guid == $ISelectPicture) { [code] } I added the code that displays currently selected item in the select menu.

Comment: So you are trying to turn this into something like an unordered list like with the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags?

Comment: Yes, a jqm basic list: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.2/docs/lists/lists-ul.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List 1:

```
$control .= '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
        $control .= '<li>';
        $control .= '<a href="'. site_url() .'/mobilegallery/gallery/'.$x[0]->attributes()->indexI.'">Bilder</a>';
        $control .= '</li>';
        $control .= '</ul>';
```

List 2, on new page:

```
$html .= '<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" data-inset="true">';
    for($i = 0, $c = $xml->COM->MOVIE->count(); $i < $c; $i++ ){

        $html .= '<li>';
        $html .= '<a>
        <img src="https://[url]/'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" id="imgThumb" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'" />
        <h1>'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'</h1>
        </a>';
        $html .= ' </li>';

    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: I guess I didn't make the question correctly, I see that when I've found a solution. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$control .= '<ul id="'. $this->_hash_value($hash, $xml_obj->value) .'" data-role="listview" data-theme="g">';
foreach($nameArr as $folder => $imageArr)
{
   foreach ($imageArr as $image) {
      $control .= '<li><a href="'. substr($folder, 1, strlen($folder)).$image .'">'. $image .'</a></li>';
   }
}
$control .= "</ul>";
```

Comment: That code makes the basic list (in post above) that I want the first single-item-list to lead to. The lists can't be visible at the same time - I haven't decided if multi-page or separate pages will be best.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the difference between a single item list and a basic list...

Comment: There's no difference in code, just in the amount of data. My single-item-list (1) is also a basic list but with just one list item. I want that item to be the latest chosen list item from the basic list (2). A click on list 1 leads to list 2, a click on any list item in list 2 leads back to list 1 and sends the value of the clicked list-2-item to list 1. Makes sense?

Comment: I have put list 2 in a new page, this part works fine. What's left to do is to make list 1 (and make it display the currently selected value from list 2 - but I'll put that in a new question). List 1 could be replaced with a button, but I with a list I'll keep the option of adding items to that list in the future open.

Comment: And +1 to @cillosis because the code works even if it's not exactly what I need.